# How to write an bash script to monitor double-click activity?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am using a dictionary named `sdcv`, which is used to translate words or phrases, and mainly worked in the terminal environment. It means that each time I want to translate one word or phrase I should open the terminal firstly and then input the word. It's really an undesirable operation.

I wonder if there any ways to use the mouse's double-click activity to finish the search.For example, wherever I am as long as I double click one word, the translation result will be showed on the terminal(If the terminal was closed before, It will open the terminal  the same time).Besides, what I want to know is whether the OS will give the permission of monitoring the double-click activity to any users.

Comment: FYI, you can highlight a word and use your mouse's middle click to paste it directly into the terminal. This doesn't answer your question asking for a bash script, but it should be helpful while you are waiting for a script to arrive.

Comment: Of course, I can copy the word and paste it by hand, but it is really inconvenient  if I do a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.
First use

```
xinput --list
```

to get the id of out input device (mouse or Touchpad)
Then get the state with

```
xinput --query-state
```

for a quick test you can do:

```
while true; do xinput --query-state 14|grep down; sleep 1; done
```